# Do I need soldered headers or can I just use male breadboard pins?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have a project that I want to make using the VEML6075.

Are the pins shown below stable when plugged in or do I need to solder them or something?

If I don't use that group of 5 pins, can I just use male to female breadboard cables to go from a Zero WH to those pin holes?

And can I just use male to male breadboard cables to go from a Zero W (no soldered headers) to those pin holes?

Will the breadboard cables fit the holes?

In general, do I ever need soldered headers or can I always just use male breadboard cable pins?

[image: VEML6075]

[image: Raspberry Pi Zero WH]

[image: Raspberry Pi Zero W]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They will need soldering to the VEML6075 otherwise the connection will be intermittent at best and more likely non-existent.

Answer (score 2):

You have obviously not tried this - the header pins will fall out if not soldered!

You can alternately solder wires to the module - I routinely do this to save space.
You can use existing DuPont cables - just cut in half and solder the wires to the module.

Comment: and strip the insulation from the module end of the wire before trying to solder it

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you don't want to solder the pins? There are pogo pin like connectors, but I would only use those if I wanted to test something.

In case you think soldering is hard. Don't be afraid. It's simple and a very useful skill. Just take your time and use pre fluxed (is that a word?) solder and a low wattage soldering iron (15-30 watts is enough).

Don't forget: you need both male and female connectors to make a proper connection.

Breadboard cables will not fit. They're to small.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes...

[image]

In my experience it's easier to prototype a new design by having soldered male header pins on all the components, and using female-to-female breadboard cables to connect everything together. The female end of a breadboard cable will grab onto a male header pin and make a reliable connection. The holes in PCBs are big and intended to have header pins or wires soldered in them.

If you want to save space like Milliways suggests, indeed cutting one end off the breadboard cable and stripping and soldering right to the PCB works well.

There's an excellent selection of breadboard cables, aka DuPont cables, available on Amazon and Ebay. I like the assortments of male-male, male-female, and female-female [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GD2BWPY).